# Micro Frontend Module Federation

Tags: angular

I am connecting my remote project to the host project in Angular 13. I have two projects, named "Project Host" and "Project Remote." Everything is set up correctly, but when I try to connect the module from the remote project to the routing file of the host project, I am encountering an error.

"Host app routing"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5oII.png)

"Error"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SvY8.png)

I want to run two applications simultaneously.

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Please edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)